# Where is the "Distance" option for hair comb tool tab in Blender 2.93.6?

Tags: particles, interface, hair

Where to find the *Distance* option for hair comb tool tab in Blender 2.93.6?

I recently updated blender and cannot find this option. I am trying to make sure hair does not go through the scalp mesh and this is how I usually would handle that.

Screenshot of previous version.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option is called *Deflect Emitter*. It's located at the top of the viewport. It has a checkbox to enable it and an input box to specify the distance.

[image: deflect emitter]

Comment: @Blunder- Thank you so much!