Can you make hair not be able to go through the mesh while sculpting it?
I am combing this strand of hair, and i would like that it didn't go through the scalp as it does right now, I have not been able to stop this from happening, so I need help.


for the (old) hair particles there is a Deflect Emitter option in the viewport's toolbar right under the menu (Edit Particles mode). For the (new) hair curves in Sculpt mode there is a similar option (Blender 3.5). It's called Use Sculpt Collision and is right next to the mirror options in the toolbar (https://www.youtube.com/live/kikaKDziNQc?feature=shared&t=75). Make sure the scalp object has no flipped normals.

I think this question is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/244513/107598
